# TF401319: Rule evaluation failed for field Assigned To

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are creating `Tasks` in VSTS using `RestAPI`. Our code was working perfectly until now. We are getting one exception while creating `Task` specifically. We are able to create `Scenario` but not `Task`. Below is the Exception which we are getting.
`Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: TF401319: Rule evaluation failed for field Assigned To.`
Can anyone suggest any fix or workaround ?

Comment: Did you create similar `Scenario` before and what's the result?

Comment: Can you share the code on one drive?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT we are creating similar scenario and tasks in vsts from Jan onwards. Till now everything was fine. This is the first time we have got this exception.

Comment: So you don't make any change for code recently, but the result is different?

Comment: Yeah..exactly !!

Comment: There was deploy a related fix on 3/2/2017, so just make sure the result was tested later then 3/2. Also, I found you reported the problem https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25120/tf401319-rule-evaluation-failed-for-field-assigned.html, let's wait for the researching results there.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I have commented on my thread in developer community regarding solution. Kindly check and respond there.

Comment: Please check the person you want to assigned has the access for the project. And what if you change another type of work item?

Comment: This is happening again with TF 2019/VS 2019.